# Stripe claims not showing in user on firestore app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

We have created an app using firestore and react and have recently added stipe as a payment option however claims are not coming through into the app

We have waited a few days as other said that was what sorted it for them however it is still not appearing for us, we can't see an issue with our setup...

Does anyone have any ideas for how to figure out the issue here?

Code we are using to get the claims is here

```
    await getAuth().currentUser.getIdToken(true);
    const decodedToken = await getAuth().currentUser.getIdTokenResult()
    return decodedToken.claims.stripeRole ? true : false;
```

And in Stripe we have set up the metadata on the product to be

```
key: firebaseRole 
value: monthly
```

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more about how you are setting the token on the user?  And what happens if you try logging out the `stripeRole` property?